How to configure CloudWatch agent custom logs
I'm using CloudWatch agent on my EC2 Instance to push logs to CloudWatch. It actually does it, but there is one tricky thing - it's the format of those logs.
Generally, agent just push my logs to cloudwatch and adds its timestamp before my and I got this:
I've tried to disable it via timestamp format in json config file but it did work, it also adds one log that is divided into several line as different logs, I've also tried to solve it.
Here is my CloudWatch agent config file:
{
  "agent": {
    "metrics_collection_interval": 60,
    "run_as_user": "root"
  },
  "logs": {
    "logs_collected": {
      "files": {
        "collect_list": [
          {
            "file_path": "my-logs.log",
            "log_group_name": "my-logs",
            "timestamp_format": "%Y-%m-%dT%H:%M:%S.%fZ",
            "multi_line_start_pattern": "{timestamp_format}",
            "retention_in_days": 365,
            "timezone": "UTC"
          }
        ]
      }
    }
  }
}

